# Scrolling into react virtualized using cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I encountered some issue with my cypress tests. I am trying to scroll into view to identify a specific element, but cypress doesn't allow me. There is an infinite scroll implemented with react virtualized.

I tried to scroll on several elements/view, also I tried to scroll directly into the entire window but it doesn't work(e.g.: cy.window().scrollTo('bottom');)

This is how my DOM looks:

I tried something similars:

```
cy.get('.ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer).contains('PlayerName').scrollIntoView();
or
cy.get('.ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer).scrollTo(0,500)  / scrollTo('bottom')
```

[image]

Do you have any ideas or are there somebody who encountered a similar issue?
I am working on a POC for a new project.

Comment: Does it give you any error? Did you try {force: true} ?

Comment: what error you are encountering when you use `cy.get('.ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer).contains('PlayerName').scrollIntoView()` ?

Comment: Yeah, Partially I solved the problem. The list is loaded dynamically, when you scroll down (infinite scroll) the next 20 players are loaded, then the next 20 players, but the first 20 loaded firstly will disappear from DOM. I will get back with the final solution as soon as I will manage to finish it. Also, @darkseid, good point to force. Thanks

Comment: @Sebastian what solution did you go with?